# Why isn't my background img covering the entire page?

Tags: html, css

I want my background image to cove the entire div but instead there are a lot of white space

HTML

```
<div class="backgroundsecction">
  <div class="backgroundimg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.backgroundimg{
 background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MAdBtV4.png);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

position: relative;
}


.backgroundsecction{
height: 900px;
width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `background-size:cover`

```css
.backgroundimg{
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MAdBtV4.png);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-size:cover;
}
.backgroundsecction{
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundsecction">
  <div class="backgroundimg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me any tips on how to get this effect? when you look at the bottom the background image doesn't move but the layer on top of it is moving. http://dimassi.com/

Comment: In  dimassi.com , what you want to do..?

Comment: if you're on PC there is a background img where the "view menu" is at the botton of the page and I want learn how the img becomes responsive to my scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If the white border bothers you around the background, use something like this:

```css
.backgroundimg {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MAdBtV4.png);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.backgroundsecction {
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="backgroundsecction">
  <div class="backgroundimg"></div>
</div>
```

If the image is smaller than the screen, than use larger image. it is generally good practice to prepare that some people could have very very large resolution displays...
Or scale it up, like @ankitapatel mentioned: with `background-size:cover;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 things as suggested

```css
    body {
        margin : 0px;   //add this 
    }
    
    .backgroundimg {
        background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MAdBtV4.png);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;    
        position: fixed;  //change fixed to cover entire
    }
    
    
    .backgroundsecction{
    height: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="backgroundsecction">
      <div class="backgroundimg"></div>
    </div>
```